# How to remove all string within brackets in a filename?

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with removing (*) from filenames.

I've tried the following code:

```
get-childitem "[Filepath]\*.txt" | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(\(*\), "") }
```

What I'm trying to get to:

Original Name: AAA BBB (DDDD) (BLAH).txt

Required Result: AAA BBB.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you required result you also removed the spaces so I think this is the regex what you are looking for:

```
'\s*\([^)]+\)'
```

[image]

Here an example:

```
'AAA BBB (DDDD) (BLAH).txt' -replace '\s*\([^)]+\)'
```

**Output:**

```
AAA BBB.txt
```

Comment: This will also work for `AAA BBB (DDDD) Additional Text (BLAH).txt` and name it `AAA BBB Additional Text.txt`, removing the extra spaces and ignoring the additional text between the bracketed pair.

Comment: Thanks, Martin!
Work awesomely! I just can't get it to work with 'Foreach'

`get-childitem "[Filepath]\*.txt" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\s*\([^)]+\)', ""}`

Comment: It has something to do with `get-childitem "[Filepath]\*.txt"`. Can't you use `get-childitem -Filter *.txt`